# What should findOneAndUpdate() return using Node.js 18.18.1 and MongoDB 7.0.2 and Node native driver 6.2.0?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Running this in my Node.js applicaton:

```js
var topic = await collection.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update);

console.log(topic);
```

seems to return the document object directly.

However the docs here:

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/6.2/classes/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/6.2/interfaces/ModifyResult.html

seem to suggest that the result should consist of three properties:

- lastErrorObject
- value
- ok

The native driver docs:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/

suggest that 6.2 is the current version of the driver.

My `package.json` has:

```
"mongodb": "^6.2.0",
```

And to double-check my app is indeed using 6.2:

```
npm list mongodb
my_app@1.0.0 C:\Users\me\Documents\REPOS\my application
└── mongodb@6.2.0
```

MongoDB version is:

```
mongosh
Current Mongosh Log ID: ****
Connecting to:          mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+2.0.2
Using MongoDB:          7.0.2
Using Mongosh:          2.0.2
```

**Edit:**

Interestingly, mongoshell returns the document directly, and this is what I am experiencing when using the native driver:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the explanation here:

https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/releases/

> ☀️ API usability improvements findOneAndX family of methods will now
> return only the found document or null by default
> (includeResultMetadata is false by default) Previously, the default
> return type of this family of methods was a ModifyResult containing
> the found document and additional metadata. This additional metadata
> is unnecessary for the majority of use cases, so now, by default, they
> will return only the found document or null.
>
> The previous behavior is still available by explicitly setting
> includeResultMetadata: true in the options.
>
> See the following [blog post](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/behavioral-changes-find-one-family-apis-node-js-driver-6-0-0) for more information.

I could be wrong, but it seems the docs are wrong in this instance (or I am reading them wrong).